# brew install gdb with python 3 does not build

Tags: gdb, homebrew

I am unable to build gdb 8.2 in mac osx mojave 10.14.3 (with gcc 8.2) using python3.7.

python3 was installed using brew install python3 and is in the PATH.

Using brew edit gdb,
I have changed `--with-python=/usr` to `/path/to/python3`
Also, added `ENV['CFLAGS']='-I/path/to/python3/include'`, `ENV['CC']='gcc'`, `ENV['CXX']='g++'`.

I keep getting `missing < Python.h > and < frameobject.h >` related error even after including CFLAGS.

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But I just ran into the same Problem and couldn't find a solution.

Have a look at the `homebrew-core` repository on GitHub. The commit [bb8b6616e51672c8011435000476b24fa242a066](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/bb8b6616e51672c8011435000476b24fa242a066) removed the `--with-python` option for some reason.

Revert that commit, change gdb version and all works fine.